# Vim auto inserts character when pressing arrow key

Tags: vim

I am currently experiencing an annoying issue, whereby when I scroll down to the end of my file in vim (version 7.4.8056) edit mode (iterm2), vim automatically adds the number '4' as long as I am pressing the down arrow, and this also happens when I've reach end of line by pressing right arrow key, instead of stopping and do nothing / beep atleast... It auto-inserts the number 4. However when I save the file, these characters are not saved onto the file.

Screenshot: [image: picture of terminal]

Comment: What's this got to do with C?  Can you remove that tag from your question?

Comment: Include your code in the question please, no snapshots

Comment: It doesn't do that on most systems.  So, you're going to need to be dreadfully precise about what you're using.  Which version of Vim?  Which platform is it running on?  Are you using a terminal emulator -- if so, which one?  What is the TERM environment variable set to?  Have you thought about not using the arrow keys if they don't work?  The `j` key moves down in command mode.  Moving with the arrow keys in insert mode is a bit iffy anyway.  What character codes does your down arrow key generate?  Does that include a `4`?

Comment: "*However when I save the file, these characters are not saved onto the file*" seems to point to a display / terminal problem.

Comment: @melpmene any idea of how I can fix it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't not use the arrows.. I'm using VIM version 7.4.805 on iTerm2 on Mac, yes a 4 is generated... Its somehow invisible too, hence I put a snapshot instead of code, I cannot delete / copy it... I can only visually see it, but can't do anything to it.... its like its not there even when I backspace it...

Comment: I use Vim on a Mac all the time (admittedly in Terminal, not iTerm2) and I disagree with your “can’t not use the arrows” assertion.  I almost never use the arrow keys in Vim. They’re a long way from the home row keys on QWERTY keyboards, whereas the “hjkl” motion keys are all together (and there are other ways of moving around files too; I don’t use the “hjkl” keys all that much either).  I can accept “I want to use the arrow keys”, but be aware that there are alternatives.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler noted... Maybe when I have resolved this issue I will give it a shot... I just tried it now with hjkl, and the same problem persists... If I press 'h' at end of line, or if I press 'j' at end of file... a '4' is inserted

Comment: Now that is weird!   Have you been futzing with terminfo?  What is `$TERM` set to? `$TERMINFO`?  It begins to sound as if there’s a bug in the terminal description used by Vim. However, that’s extremely unusual unless you’ve been tinkering with these configuration settings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Haven't been fiddling... I don't know how to set $TERM / $TERMINFO... please advise, possibly without knowing... I could've

Comment: It was at best a long shot.  You'd know if you'd been tinkering with terminfo etc.  Maybe you can show what `$TERM` is set to in the environment and the output from running `infocmp` (no arguments needed).  There's an outside chance that'll allow someone to spot the problem.

Comment: I had to reconfigure my .vimrc settings